# what is the cache directory for in my theme? (version control it?)

Tags: cache, version-control

I was wondering what processes exactly use the `cache` directory inside my theme's directory. More specifically, I am wondering if I should add any of those files to my git repo.

Comment: What theme are you using? Without knowing, it's hard to say for sure, but, as a rule of thumb, files in a directory named "cache" typically do not need to be added to an SCM repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use someway "compilable" WordPress theme (are they exist?!) cache-dir *may contain* theme-files, processed by some tools and prepared for using by httpd-server of site.

As all and any artifacts, constructed from **versioned data**, these files can and have be excluded from versioning - **everybody** will be able to **rebuild** these files from *versioned source files*